# Java Convert String to Hexadecimal For Server UDP

Tags: java

```
public class ServerUDP {
   private static final int ECHOMAX = 255;  // Maximum size of echo datagram
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   
      if (args.length != 1)  // Test for correct argument list
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter(s): <Port>");
   
      int servPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   
      DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(servPort);
      DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[ECHOMAX], ECHOMAX);
   
      for (;;) {  // Run forever, receiving and echoing datagrams
         socket.receive(packet);     // Receive packet from client
         System.out.println("Handling client at " +
            packet.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " on port " + packet.getPort());
         String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
         System.out.println("Received: " + message);
         System.out.println("From Client: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
         System.out.println("Port: " + packet.getPort());
         StringBuilder sendmessage = new StringBuilder();
         sendmessage.append(message); 
         sendmessage.reverse(); 
         message = sendmessage.toString();
         System.out.println("Hex Message: " + message);
         byte[] messageByte = message.getBytes();
         packet.setData(messageByte);
         socket.send(packet);
         
         }
      
   }
}
```

Basically, for previous work I made a Client-Server UDP Java app that took in a string that was entered on the client side, then the server took the message and reversed it. Now I basically have to do the same thing, but convert the string to hexadecimal instead of reversing, so effectively, replace the reverse method with something to convert for hexadecimal. What would be a good way to do this given the code?

Comment: A lot of programming is about breaking a problem down. If this question is only about hexadecimal numbers, then your [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) shouldn't be doing any networking. If this question is actually about UDP, then please edit the question to make it more clear what this has to do with networking.

Answer (score 0):

If, you try to convert the ascii string to hex you can use somethink like

```java
public String asciiToHex(String asciiStr) {
        char[] chars = asciiStr.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
        for (char ch : chars) {
            hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) ch));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }
```

Can you send a example of conversion you have to made?

ex:

```
INPUT: 001001
OUTPUT: 303031303031
```

Comment: Why do you imply ASCII? [`char`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) is 16 bits wide and Unicode is standard nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

First the existing code makes the assumption that the `byte[]` data is not binary data and convertible to/from a Unicode `String` using the default encoding of the platform. That is inefficient (conversions, twice the space as `char` is two bytes),
and easily corruptable, and sender and receiver should run under the same encoding.

If you indeed want to reverse **text**, then your code is right, and could deal with multi-byte sequences for Unicode symbols.

But then agree on a specific encoding, Charset. For instance StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 or UTF_8. For `getBytes` and `new String`.

Otherwise

```
     byte[] message = packet.getData();;
     System.out.println("Received: " + Arrays.toString(message));
     System.out.println("From Client: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
     System.out.println("Port: " + packet.getPort());
     byte[] sendmessage = new byte[message.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < message.length; ++i) {
         sendmessage[i] = message(message.length - 1 - i);
     }
     packet.setData(sendmessage);
     socket.send(packet);
```

A hexadecimal dump would be:

```
     byte[] message = packet.getData();;
     System.out.println("Received: " + Arrays.toString(message));
     System.out.println("From Client: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
     System.out.println("Port: " + packet.getPort());
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message.length * 2);
     for (int i = 0; i < message.length; ++i) {
         sendmessage.append(String.format("%02x", message(message[i) & 0xFF);
     }
     packet.setData(sendmessage.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
     socket.send(packet);
```

`%02x` gives `0-9a-f` and `%02X` gives `0-9A-F`.

You might want to append "\r\n" to `sendmessage` as the result seems to be text (unlikely).